# Call np.sqrt in cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def cy_sum(int n):
    cdef double s=0
    cdef int i 
    for i in range(n):
        s += np.sqrt(i)
    return s
```

[image: cython -a]

I have the code for calculating the sum of square root as above.
By using `cython -a`, I got the result as in the picture. 
The cython code interacts with python at function call `np.sqrt(i)`, and there is no improvement compared to pure python code.

I don't know if I have done something wrong in specifying the type of variables. 
There are other solutions, such as using `i**(1/2)` or import the function `sqrt` from `clib`, but I would like to understand why cython cannot compile np.sqrt in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Im curious, does `i**(1/2)` compile to a faster solution?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't interact with python.

Comment: Reading from [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) I'd infer that `np.sqrt` simply wants a python int object, so Cython cannot do anything other than creating one to get the result.

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to `cimport numpy as cnp`, then it becomes apparent which functions are slow usual python functionality (you will have to call it via `np.xxxx` e.g. `np.sqrt`) and which funcionality is  fast cython (called via `cnp.xxx` for example `cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when Cython sees a python function call, it is treated as an opaque operation.  Cython might elide a bit of calling overhead, but otherwise it will generate the exact same semantics as if that function was called from python.

Certain numpy constructs, such as the `ndarray[dtype]` type are special cased by the Cython compiler to generate more efficient code.  numpy ufuncs are not, so to cython `np.sqrt` is just another python function, so it can do nothing better than calling back into python to run it.

Other python accelerators, such as `numba` will intercept the call to `np.sqrt` and rewrite it to the equivalent low level code.